# Python - Applying function to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2D array converted from a CSV spreadsheet with data using pandas. I would like to apply a function on the data that also includes elements of the array.

My function:

```
def calc_pol(a, b, R = 0.08314462618, T = 298.15):
           return a * b * R * T
```

I can call it on the data array in the following manner, where a and b are determined from the data array:

```
calc_pol(
        a = data[0,0], b=data[0,1]
        )
```

Which will return the value I'm looking for. Now, the organization of the spreadsheet was in columns so the way the data is incorporated is that if I:

```
print(data[0])
```

I get the following (arbitrary) values:

20 40 60 80 100 120

I want to feed my function 20*40 (data[0,0]| * data[0,1]) --> save value in new array. 60 * 80 (data[0,2]| * data[0,3]) --> save value in new array and do the same for 80 * 100.

Each "column" has 80 values, so I would like to iterate over i in range 0 : 80, by employing a for loop or some other function but I am unsure on how to proceed, my index keeps "getting out of range. I appreciate any insights you can offer!

Comment: This is very confusing to read.  Please post your reproducible code to start.  We can't fix your index problem by guessing.  Also provide sample input data with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like a simple column operation in pandas, there is no need to use indexing by number or for loop if you have column names:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c'+str(i):[i]*4 for i in range(6)})

def calc_pol(df, col1, col2, R = 0.08314462618, T = 298.15):
    return df[col1] * df[col2] * R * T

df['c6'] = calc_pol(df, 'c1', 'c2', R = 0.08314462618, T = 298.15)
df['c7'] = calc_pol(df, 'c3', 'c4', R = 0.08314462618, T = 298.15)
```

```
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6          c7
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   49.579141   297.474844
1   0   1   2   3   4   5   49.579141   297.474844
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   49.579141   297.474844
3   0   1   2   3   4   5   49.579141   297.474844
```

Comment: I really like this answer as it directly manipulates the pandas dataframe without having to store everything in an array, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and store all the results in the `res` list:

```
number_of_rows = 80
res = [calc_pol(a = data[0,i], b=data[0,i+1]) for i in range(number_of_rows - 1)]
```

at this point `res[0]` contains `20*40`, `res[1]`contains `60 * 80` and so on...